# Why Vehicle's Engine back wheel driven?

Tags: classical-mechanics, forces

Why most of the vehicles Engine Driving the Back wheels instead of Front Wheel. Including Cycle,two wheeler, bus, Car, Heavy Vehicles, I am guessing some science is there behind this, I dont know what it will be.

Any one can tell me why it is back wheel driven ?

And what basis they choosing the mode wheel drive ?

Comment: If you think most cars are driven from just the back wheels, you clearly don't live in an area that gets snow ;)

Comment: Yes. i am not belong to snow region,just now i came to know such kind of vehicles also there. On what basis they are choosing the option either back wheel or front wheel ?

Comment: In the UK most cars have front wheel drive.

Comment: @John Thanks for the information. But my question is why front and why back ?

Comment: More an engineering than physics question, I think.  It's easier to build a vehicle where the steering wheels are not simultaneously responsible for delivering power.  The drivetrain to the wheels is simpler.

Comment: I agree that this is an engineering question and better suited to [the Engineering Stack Exchange](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/). I've had a quick look there and somewhat to me surprise the question doesn't seem to have been asked before. However I think you should do [the obvious Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=front%20wheel%20drive%20versus%20rear%20wheel%20drive) first.

Answer (score 1):

Due to air resistance, rear-wheel drive produces greater power, torque, and fuel efficiency than front-wheel drive.

Air resistance applies a force that pushes the body of the car backwards. This moves the center of gravity backwards as the body shifts due to the stress. Also this force tends to be above the center of gravity which provides a torque that increases the weight on the back wheels compared to the front. Therefore the weight on the front wheels is less than the weight on the back wheels.

Rear-wheel drive is used in race cars, pick-up trucks, and other large vehicles.

Comment: I don't understand what air resistance has to do with it.

Comment: this is wrong.  For one thing,  rear-wheel drive got a major head start because it's hard to drive steerable wheels.  60 years after Henry Ford, not so much.